# false value is ignored

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a registration form that checks onchange if a username already exists and displays a BS alert. The function to check this uses Ajax. Answers to my earlier question led me to improve my code to use callback in my Ajax function. So now I have the following code:

HTML:

```
onchange="callAjax('gebruikersnaam', document.getElementById('gebruikersnaam').value, checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam)"
```

JavaScript main function:

```
function callAjax(arg1, arg2, callback){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) { 
        callback(request.responseText);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'An error occurred during your request: ' +  request.status + ' ' + request.statusText;
    } 
  }
request.open("POST", "core/functions/checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send(arg1+"="+arg2);    
}
```

JavaScript callback function:

```
function checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam(result) {
if(result == "1") {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
    return false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '';
}
}
```

Now I have a generic Ajax request that I can re-use by feeding it different parameters. So thanks for that. Can someone confirm if I am using the callback functionality correctly?

Now, what I really want is to re-use the function `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()` when the form is submitted. I have the following code:

HTML:

```
 <form action="register.php" onsubmit="return validate()" name="registerForm" method="post" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
```

JavaScript:

```
function validate() {
var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("message");
if(checkPassword() === false ) {
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Kies een wachtwoord van minimaal 3 en maximaal 30 tekens.</div>';
            return false;
} else if(checkPasswordsMatch() === false){
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen.</div>';
            return false;
} else if(checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam() === false){
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = 
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
            return false;
}
```

The functions `checkPassword()` and `checkPasswordsMatch()` don't use Ajax and they work as expected within the function `validate()`. But when I test the function `validate()` for `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()` it doesn't work. It ignores the `false` value and submits the form. I thought the use of a callback function should solve this, but apparently I am still doing something wrong.  Please enlighten me and thanks for your time.

Comment: Read this to start: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's evaluate whats happening step by step:

The `validate()` function calls `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()`  without passing any parameter.

Inside `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()`, value of `result` is undefined, the `else` block gets executed that  does not return anything.

In `validate()` the check `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam() === false` evaluates to `false`.

Since `validate()` does not return false, This makes javascript to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution, perhaps it will help some other novice.

I decided to evaluate `validate()` by a variable `checkBG`, that should get its value from 'result' inside `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()`. But since `checkBG` should be available to other functions, I made it a global variable by not using the `var` keyword, like this:

```
function checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam(result) {
checkBG = result;
if(checkBG == "1") {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '';
}
}
```

Then I used that variable checkBG as the condition in my `validate()` function:

```
function validate() {
var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("message");
if(checkPassword() === false ) {
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Kies een wachtwoord van minimaal 3 en maximaal 30 tekens.</div>';
            return false;
} else if(checkPasswordsMatch() === false){
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen.</div>';
            return false;
} else if(checkBG == "1"){
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = 
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
            return false;
} 
}
```

This actually worked and hours of torture have finally resulted in triomph! Thanks again to Kashif who helped me on my way.